# When should I use Object type vs straight Kotlin file

Tags: android, kotlin

While working with Kotlin, I see you can define methods in a Kotlin file that has no class or object type (i.e. a file without `class Test` or `object Test`). I also see when you put methods into a Kotlin file without the `class` or `object` keywords, you need to import the method (i.e. `import com.package.testMethod`) to the file you want to use it. A little more context, I was trying to make some utility methods and started tinkering with both `object` and kotlin file with no class/object

My question is what is the use case for having a methods that aren't in some kind of `object` file? And when would you want to use this over something like `object`?

Comment: In an app, I would lean towards putting the functions on some type, whether that is an `object`, an existing type (extension functions), or some type that you create. The Kotlin standard library makes extensive use of top-level functions, though. Think of `listOf()` and `mapOf()`, for example. Popular Kotlin extension libraries also use top-level functions: `flow()` for creating a `Flow` with the coroutines library, `startKoin()` in Koin, and so on. In the end, it is about promoting ease of use for widely-used bits of functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin top-levels functions vs object function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862918/kotlin-top-levels-functions-vs-object-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either put your methods in the top-level declaration or inside an `object`. It's all about whether you want to pollute namespaces or not. You can have a function named `X` in an `object` and you can still have a function name `X` in a different `object` file since you can refer to specific method with the help of their `object` name. But you won't be able to do this if you declare methods top-level, each method would need to have a unique signature name(not counting overloaded methods).

Additionally, `object` can have supertypes, meaning you can inherit other classes or implement interfaces. Neither introduces more technical capability over another. If you define variables in an object or as top-level, both will be initialized lazily.

In short, it depends if you want to pollute namespaces or not.

Comment: So which implementation pollutes the namespace?

Comment: The one without `object`

Comment: If the object has nothing in it other than functions, I don't think there's really a difference in terms of "namespace pollution". Top-level functions are namespaced by their package, while functions in objects are namespaced by the object's class name and package. Therefore, you can create equal levels of namespacing by creating a package rather than an object (e.g. `com.example.MyObject.myFunction` vs `com.example.mypackage.myFunction`).

Comment: Agreed, what if there is more than one file in the same package, then there could be a naming conflict, but using an `object`, there won't be a naming conflict. I think that if we want to work in the same package, then `object` could be handy otherwise declaring methods top-level is the way to go.