# @file:JvmName vs @JvmStatic in companion object

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm migrating part of application from Java to Kotlin and have a question about that.

What is preferable or better way ?

1. **File with annonation @file:JvmName and funtion inside**

```
@file:JvmName("ClassX")

fun funX() {}
```

or

2. **Typical class with @JvmStatic annotation inside companion object**

```
class ClassX {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun funX() {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's look at the decompiled code to answer this question.

Kotlin file with a `@JvmName` annotation like yours:

```
@file:JvmName("ClassX")

fun funX() {}
```

will be compiled into a bytecode, analogous to this Java code:

```java
@JvmName(
   name = "ClassX"
)
public final class ClassX {
   public static final void funX() {
   }
}
```

Pretty similar to what you'd probably write when using Java, right?

A Kotlin class with a companion object like this:

```
class ClassX {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun funX() {}
    }
}
```

is analogous to this Java code:

```java
public final class ClassX {
   public static final ClassX.Companion Companion = new ClassX.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker)null);

   @JvmStatic
   public static final void funX() {
      Companion.funX();
   }

   public static final class Companion {
      @JvmStatic
      public final void funX() {
      }

      private Companion() {
      }

      // $FF: synthetic method
      public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
         this();
      }
   }
}
```

As you see, class with a companion object will generate more code.

Is it good or bad? You decide. I'd say it's bad and it's better to use a file with `@JvmName` annotation. There is also a discussion on Kotlin's forum about this topic: [read the best practices.](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practices-for-top-level-declarations/2198/3?u=madhead)

BTW, you can look at the bytecode and decompiled Java code in IntelliJ IDEA via "Tools" -> "Kotlin" -> "Show Kotlin Bytecode".

Comment: In addition, they'll be referred to the same way from Java, but not from Kotlin and recommended practice in Kotlin is to use top-level functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862918/kotlin-top-levels-functions-vs-object-function

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyRomanov, I've linked Dmitry's statement from the forum here.