# How to create compile-time constant in Kotlin from enum?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, compile-time-constant, graphql-spqr

I have an annotation that requires `defaultValue` to be compile-time constant. I take `defaultValue` from `enum` below:

```
enum class RaceType {
    MARATHON,
    SPRINT;

    companion object {
        fun apply(type: RaceType): RaceDto {
            return when (type) {
                MARATHON -> MarathonDto()
                SPRINT -> SprintDto()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `dto`s are the following:

```
interface RaceDto {
}

data class MarathonDto: RaceDto

data class SprintDto: RaceDto
```

when I use annotation `@QraphQLArgument(defaultValue = RaceType.SPRINT.name)` Kotlin requires `RaceType.SPRINT.name` to be compile-time constant.

Annotation implementation itself:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface GraphQLArgument {
    String NONE = "\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\ue000\ue001\ue002\n\t\t\t\t\n";
    String NULL = "\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\ue000\ue001\ue002\ue003\n\t\t\t\t\n";

    String name();

    String description() default "";

    String defaultValue() default "\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\ue000\ue001\ue002\n\t\t\t\t\n";

    Class<? extends DefaultValueProvider> defaultValueProvider() default JsonDefaultValueProvider.class;
}
```

I looked through [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038721/constants-in-kotlin-whats-a-recommended-way-to-create-them) but don't see a way how it can be resolved. I also found [article](https://blog.egorand.me/where-do-i-put-my-constants-in-kotlin/) related to the topic but nothing worked so far.

Side note: I cannot change annotation since it is from the library and I cannot change the library as well.

To summarize, is there a way to make from `enum` compile-time constant in Kotlin to use in an annotation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> is there a way to make from `enum` compile-time constant in Kotlin to use in an annotation?

No, because formally `enum`s [aren't compile-time constants in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28296706/185498).

However please consider the `sealed` classes:

```kotlin
sealed class RaceType {
    object MARATHON: RaceType() {
        const val name = "MARATHON" // copy-paste is required here until https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16304
    }
    object SPRINT: RaceType()

    companion object {
        fun apply(type: RaceType): RaceDto {
            return when (type) { // the check is in compile time, because of sealed class
                MARATHON -> MarathonDto()
                SPRINT -> SprintDto()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A little part of copy-paste is still required. Please vote on [kotlin compiler bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16304) or [follow this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/class-property-name-should-be-compile-time-constant/9331/2?u=imanushin).

However, as I understand, this doesn't solve your issue with `@QraphQLArgument(defaultValue = RaceType.SPRINT.name)` unfortunately, because the name of class is not the same with value. In the other words, with sealed classes you need to write code to convert input strings to them.

Comment: Thx. It is a good workaround and, at least, I know why I couldn't find a solution for it.