# Room Dao query for fixed Object

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Recently I faced a situation that need to query for specific object type but without passing it with method I could not find any way. So I want to do some thing like:

```
@Query(" select * from table_a where type = ENUM_A")
fun queryForTypeA()
```

But its alternative bellow is works but I do not want to pass any thing.

```
@Query(" select * from table_a where type =:type")
fun queryForTypeA(type: EnumType = ENUM_A)
```

The thing is if I find out the proper way in some other query I wanna exclude some other ENUMs so passing in function is not working there and no sense. I wanna achieve something like this:

```
@Query(" select * from table_a where type NOT ENUM_A")
fun queryForAllTypesExceptA()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey after lots of tries I found that I can pass object or enum equal value I created in type convertor as fixed string.
Because best way of saving complicated classes or enum is save them as String so we create two methods one is `fromString(value: String):MyEnum` and second is `toString(value:MyEnum):String` in typeConvertor class.

Seems that Room can convert that string value using type convertors.
So I changed to like this and it works:

```
@Query(" select * from table_a where type != 'ENUM_A' ")
fun queryForAllTypesExceptA()
```

And another point that `NOT` won't work for it and you have to use `!=`

Answer (score 0):

Try altering the second approach, but define a default value for `type` like:

```
@Query(" select * from table_a where type =:type")
fun queryForTypeA(type: EnumType = EnumType.A)
```

This way you don't have to specify a value for `type` at the call sites.

Comment: I also did this but did not mention. So looking for passing hardcoded value to query. the reason is in some query I wanna exclude some others so I have to add list of enum in exclude query so that not making sense.

Answer (score 0):

> enums are static constants but are not compile-time constants. Just
> like any other classes enum is loaded when the first time needed.
>
> you can't have dynamically defined arguments for your `@Query`
> annotation.

You can either put your type in a `companion` object of class  or you can use sealed class like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827126/how-to-create-compile-time-constant-in-kotlin-from-enum#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=answer%20was%20accepted%E2%80%A6-,is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20make%20from%20enum%20compile%2Dtime,compile%2Dtime%20constants%20in%20Java.&text=A%20little%20part%20of%20copy%2Dpaste%20is%20still%20required.)

```
@Query(" select * from table_a where type"+ "="+ companionEnum_a) 
fun queryForTypeA()
```

Make sure your companionEnum_a is compile-time constant. That is it should be `const val companionEnum_a`

Comment: Can you gimme the source link of your quota comment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296547/execution-order-of-enum-in-java/28296706#28296706

Comment: For sure, let me try your solution.

Comment: If you mean create scaled class and put it in companion object, still I got 'Annotation argument must be compile time" and still can not put them in query. :(

Comment: You can just use a normal class with companion object

Comment: It is not working. You can just test it your self, try to pass any companion object in room dao queris.

Comment: In any room dao as my example in question I try to pass that companion object as "...= $companionObject  "

Comment: @Query(" select * from table_a where type = $companionEnum_a ")
fun queryForTypeA()

Comment: @Mahdi I have updated the answer for you. I have checked it and it's working fine

Comment: This code can never compile, how did you + in strings and pass enum?!

Comment: I thought we are clear that you can't use enum in-room query make string const in the companion object. it's a simple string concatenation

Comment: Do you think my problem was companion object?! For sure I was using companion object as beginnings  for passing, but for enum value it wont accept string as enum or any object that we have type convertor for it. I will see error like: "SQL error or missing database (no such column: enum_1)"

Comment: Don't use enum, you can't. use string that's what I'm saying

Comment: But Room wont recognize my string as Enum.

Comment: Yes it won't , because you can't do that . You must use string not enum

Comment: I mean if I pass string as field of enum room wont compile it, so do you mean that I have to change my field to string in table so that can make this work?!

Comment: Yes , because room can't understand enum

Comment: Mmm we just back to my question first point. So your answer not helping me, I can not change whole tables to string so that can use string in query.